# solr query : with the Wildcard Searches Type *

Tags: solr

the filed define in the schema.xml :

`<field name="typeDesc" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

The typeDesc store the values like 公立, 公立，三甲, 公立，二甲。

The question is when I query typeDesc:*三甲*, there is nothing, but when I query typeDesc:*公立* or typeDesc:*三*  or typeDesc:*甲* or typeDesc:三甲, they all could find the result like 公立，三甲。 I want to know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not too familiar with word breaking rules for kanji, I'm going to guess that the reason is that when you're doing wildcard searches, analysis for the field isn't performed. If 三 and 甲 are split into separate tokens, the wild card match will not find any token matching your search.

You can confirm this by using the analysis tab of the admin page to see which tokens an indexed term is being broken into.

Possible solutions would be to index the terms in a single string field as well and do wildcard matches against that, or use a KeywordTokenizer for your text field if you need further processing before storing the token (the keyword tokenizer will keep the text as one single token). You could also use an ngramfilter and drop the wildcards.

Comment: when I query typeDesc:"三甲",  there has the result.  As far as I know, that is a accurate query, so what's the different with the query  typeDesc:*三甲*.

Comment: As I mention in my post, when you use a wildcard, analysis is not performed. "Analysis" is what happens with a value before it's being stored or matched to the stored values, for example broken into separate words or phrases. In this case my guess is that 三 and 甲 are broken into separate tokens, meaning that they're stored separately. When you're using the wildcard search, the analysis step (that splits them into separate tokens) are skipped, and Solr looks for a stored token of 三甲. There is no token like that (since it's split when stored), so you don't get a hit. Use analysis page to confirm